# R markdown loops

Tags: r, loops, markdown

I've been trying this code for a while, don't understand why it's not working (it was actually so worse than that in the beginning, but still not what I need)

```
for(i in names(swiss)){
print(paste(names(swiss[i]),", which mean is", round(sapply(swiss, mean), 2)))
}

## [1] "Fertility , which mean is 70.14" "Fertility , which mean is 50.66"
## [3] "Fertility , which mean is 16.49" "Fertility , which mean is 10.98"
## [5] "Fertility , which mean is 41.14" "Fertility , which mean is 19.94"
## [1] "Agriculture , which mean is 70.14" "Agriculture , which mean is 50.66"
## [3] "Agriculture , which mean is 16.49" "Agriculture , which mean is 10.98"
## [5] "Agriculture , which mean is 41.14" "Agriculture , which mean is 19.94"
## [1] "Examination , which mean is 70.14" "Examination , which mean is 50.66"
## [3] "Examination , which mean is 16.49" "Examination , which mean is 10.98"
## [5] "Examination , which mean is 41.14" "Examination , which mean is 19.94"
## [1] "Education , which mean is 70.14" "Education , which mean is 50.66"
## [3] "Education , which mean is 16.49" "Education , which mean is 10.98"
## [5] "Education , which mean is 41.14" "Education , which mean is 19.94"
## [1] "Catholic , which mean is 70.14" "Catholic , which mean is 50.66"
## [3] "Catholic , which mean is 16.49" "Catholic , which mean is 10.98"
## [5] "Catholic , which mean is 41.14" "Catholic , which mean is 19.94"
## [1] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 70.14"
## [2] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 50.66"
## [3] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 16.49"
## [4] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 10.98"
## [5] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 41.14"
## [6] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 19.94"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another base R option using `colMeans` + `stack` + `paste`

```
do.call(paste, cbind(stack(round(colMeans(swiss), 2)), ", which mean is")[c(2, 3, 1)])
```

which gives

```
[1] "Fertility , which mean is 70.14"
[2] "Agriculture , which mean is 50.66"
[3] "Examination , which mean is 16.49"
[4] "Education , which mean is 10.98"       
[5] "Catholic , which mean is 41.14"
[6] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 19.94"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, we are looping over the column names and inside the loop, again another loop with `sapply` which is not needed.  Instead, we get the `mean` by extracting the column as a `vector` with the corresponding column name, `swiss[[i]]` and `round`

```
for(i in names(swiss)){
  print(paste(i,", which mean is", round(mean(swiss[[i]]), 2)))
 }
#[1] "Fertility , which mean is 70.14"
#[1] "Agriculture , which mean is 50.66"
#[1] "Examination , which mean is 16.49"
#[1] "Education , which mean is 10.98"
#[1] "Catholic , which mean is 41.14"
#[1] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is 19.94"
```

NOTE: when we do `in`, the value `i` is each of those column names.  We don't need to do again `names(swiss[i])`

---

Or use vectorized option as `paste` and `colMeans` are vectorized

```
paste(names(swiss), ", which mean is ",  round(colMeans(swiss), 2))
#[1] "Fertility , which mean is  70.14"    
#[2] "Agriculture , which mean is  50.66"    
#[3] "Examination , which mean is  16.49"     
#[4] "Education , which mean is  10.98"     
#[5] "Catholic , which mean is  41.14"   
#[6] "Infant.Mortality , which mean is  19.94"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! could I only ask you what the double square parenthesis is for? I'm super new... still learning! Thank you!

Comment: @CeciliaBonucchi It all relates to subsetting a data.frame or list.  The `[[` will directly get the column as a vector.  where as `swiss[i]` (if it is a data.frame) returns a single column `data.frame` insteda of a vector.  You may also use `swiss[,i]` i.e. with `,` to separate which will also coerce to vector if it s a data.frame

Comment: @CeciliaBonucchi You may check the structure or class `str(swiss[1])`, `str(swiss[,1])`, `str(swiss[[1]])`